# How does Jenkins resolves conflict in plugins version dependency

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, offline

Hello to all Jenkins administrators,

Do you know how does Jenkins plugin update mechanism behave when there is a dependency on two different versions of the same plugin?

We're running Jenkins on an air gapped network.
I would like to download the *.hpi/*.jpi plugin files with their dependencies.

(We're running Jenkins version 2.89.2, so we need to download previous versions of the plugins compatible with this Jenkins version.)

I'm getting version 2.30 of the plugin "Pipeline: Groovy" (workflow-cps).

It has a direct dependency on the plugin workflow-step-api version 2.9,
but also a transitive dependency on version 2.7 of this plugin.

workflow-cps:2.30 -> workflow-step-api:**2.9**

workflow-cps:2.30 -> workflow-api:2.11 -> workflow-step-api:**2.7**

Does Jenkins update mechanism take the latest version?

Thanks,

Eyal